# Armijo Backtracking and Steepest Descent to find Local Minimum

Tags: optimization, algorithms, matlab, numerical-optimization

I have to find the local minimum of the following function using Steepest Descent:

$f(x,y)=3x^2-3y^2+8xy$

Analytically, by equating the gradient to the zero vector, you get $(0,0)$ to be the local minimum.

I implemented the following function in MATLAB to get the answer:

```
function [x,xk]=SteepDesc(f,df,x0,tol,maxiter,tau,beta,ainit)

if nargin <8
    ainit=10;
end
    if nargin<7
        beta=0.1;
    end
    if nargin<6
        tau=0.5;
    end
    if nargin<5
        maxiter=100;
    end
    if nargin<4
        tol=1e-6;
    end

    x=x0;
    xk=x0;
    gradf=df(x);
    p=-gradf;
    k=0;

    while norm(p)>tol && k<maxiter
        alpha=ainit;
        while f(x+alpha*p)>f(x)+alpha*beta*p'*gradf
            alpha=alpha*tau;
        end
        x=x+alpha*p;
        gradf=df(x);
        p=-gradf;
        k=k+1;
        xk(:,k+1)=x;
    end
```

After implementing it, I got:

```
clear;
f= @(x) 3*(x(1))^2-3*(x(2))^2+8*x(1)*x(2);
df= @(x) [6*x(1)+8*x(2);-6*x(2)+8*x(1)];
x0=[0.0001;0.0001];

[z,zk]=SteepDesc(f,df,x0);
z

>>z =

  1.0e+194 *

   -1.1229
    2.8698
```

However, why does the Newton approach give me (0,0), while steepest descent gives me these values?

Comment: What have you done to try to debug this?  You might start by looking at the values of $\alpha$ and the function values in each iteration.

Comment: What do you expect the minimum to be?

Comment: I actually just realized that (0,0) is a saddle point for this function... the minimum is going to be a negative infinity.

Comment: However, why does the Newton approach give me (0,0), while steepest descent gives me these values?

Comment: Where do you show “the Newton approach” in your question? The intersections of this surface with vertical planes through the origin are parabolas, so if you approach the origin from certain directions it will indeed look like a minimum.